# Telerik RadWindow containing user control not firing client Events?

Tags: c#, ajax, telerik, telerik-grid

I have implemented a Telerik RadWindow which contains a User control(.ascx). The User control contains grid which populates after clicking on search button. The grid population happens via Ajax implementing RadAjaxManager. All the ajax settings are kept in a separate file(master Page File) Makup below.

The main issue that I am not able to figure out is that the search button is not firing the client events in this case the requestStart and requestEnd.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="radAjaxManager" runat="server">
    <ClientEvents OnRequestStart="requestStart" OnResponseEnd="responseEnd" />
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="generalOrderControl">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="generalOrderControl">  </telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>    
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

The main thing that the client events do is block the UI ($.blockUI())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution :- Whatever contols are inside the RAD window that is the user control should be inside the RAD Ajax panel.

Answer (score 0):

Write client side events(requeststart ,responseEnd ) in your aspx rather than ascx, in file from where you have placed your custom control

Hope it will work

Comment: That is in a separate js file whose refernce has been added in the Master page. It is working for all other control in the application but not working for user controls inside the rad. Sorry for not providing the information earlier.