# Server side OnClick Event Not Firing on button in telerik's RadWindow

Tags: vb.net, telerik, asp.net-2.0, radwindow

Okay so I've got an issue with the RadWindow control.

I have a button on the inside of a RadWindow. The button needs to respond to a server side event on the code behind. I've gone as far as **getting this code to work**  in a test app but I can't seem to get it working in an actual application.

I've looked [in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417341/telerik-radwindow-containing-user-control-not-firing-client-events) [a](http://www.telerik.com/forums/button-inside-radwindow-content-template-will-not-postback-asynchronously-nor-will-it-call-server-side-validation) [few](http://www.telerik.com/forums/button-click-event-not-firing-f5e7df24bd76) [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619395/onclick-not-working-when-i-use-both-onclick-onclientclick) [places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417341/telerik-radwindow-containing-user-control-not-firing-client-events) and have used what I've learned to get a test app that works. But that same bit of code is not working in my app. The only key differences I can tell are that I've got a reference to the Script manager in a seperate file and that I am using .net version 2 in the actual app but 4.0 in the test app. **What am I doing wrong here?**

#### The Code Behind (which is not firing)

```
Protected Sub btnClearFilterValues_OnClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnClearFilterValues.Click
    'clears a bunch of values 
    'this never hits'
End Sub

Protected Sub btnFilterCourses_OnClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnFilterCourses.Click
    'Code executes filter'
    'this never hits'
End Sub
```

#### Separate header referencing the scripts contains the following

```
<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" ScriptMode="Release">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js"></asp:ScriptReference>
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js"></asp:ScriptReference>
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js"></asp:ScriptReference>
    </Scripts>
</telerik:RadScriptManager>
```

#### The Markup

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
    </telerik:RadAjaxManager>

        <telerik:RadCodeBlock runat="server" ID="rdbScripts">
            <script type="text/javascript">
            <!--
    //-->

    //adds jquery to the global or "window" level namespace
    window.$ = $telerik.$;

    function showDialog() {
        var wnd = $find("<%=modalPopup.ClientID %>");
        wnd.show();
        Sys.Application.remove_load(showDialog);
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnFilter").click(function (event) {
            showDialog();
        });
    });
    </script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>

    <telerik:RadAjaxPanel runat="server" ID="rapConfiguration" HorizontalAlign="NotSet">
        <telerik:RadWindow ID="modalPopup" runat="server" Width="720px" Height="292px" Modal="True" Title="Filter Courses">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnFilterCourses" runat="server" OnClick="btnFilterCourses_OnClick" Style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: 0" Text="Filter Courses" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnClearFilterValues" OnClick="btnClearFilterValues_OnClick" runat="server" Style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;" Text="Clear" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </telerik:RadWindow>
    </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<asp:Button ID="btnFilterCourses" runat="server" OnClick="btnFilterCourses_OnClick" Style="margin right: auto; margin-left: 0" Text="Filter Courses" UseSubmitBehavior="False" AutoPostBack="TRUE" />

<asp:Button ID="btnClearFilterValues" OnClick="btnClearFilterValues_OnClick" runat="server" Style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;" Text="Clear" UseSubmitBehavior="False" AutoPostBack="TRUE" />
```

You could try this, i've added an 'AutoPostBack' property.